# Submitting 2 https requests in 2 minute interval using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Following is my python code, where am trying to run 2 https requests, first one to start my databrick cluster.  Since the cluster startup takes around 2 minutes, I am trying to have time.sleep for 2 minutes and then submit my second https to run a databricks job.  These are runing from my AWS Lambda.  I have tried with AWS Step function as well, but am getting different errors and hence decided to go with lambda.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import boto3
import time
import urllib
import re
import pymysql
import sys
import requests
import base64
import time

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
domain = 'mydatabricks.cloud.databricks.com'
tokenStr = 'token:tokenstr'


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = requests.post('https://%s/api/2.0/clusters/start' % (domain),
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + base64.standard_b64encode(tokenStr)},
    json = {"cluster_id": "ddddd-sss23-2232323"})
    seconds = 200
    time.sleep(seconds)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("slept for seconds : ", str(seconds))
        print("Cluster started / completed successfully ***************")
    else:
        print ("Error in starting cluster !!!!!!!!!!!!!! %s: %s" % (response.json()["error_code"], response.json()["message"]))

    #time.sleep(180)
    while True:
        try:
            response2 = requests.post('https://%s/api/2.0/jobs/run-now' % (domain),
            headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + base64.standard_b64encode(tokenStr)},
            json = {"job_id": 12345})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(180)

    #   if response2.status_code == "INVALID_STATE":
    #    print("Job started / completed successfully ***************")
    #else:
    #    print ("Error in running the job 28885 !!!!!!!!!!!!!! %s: %s" % (response2.json()["error_code"], response2.json()["message"]))
```

The error message am getting with the above is :

```
2018-08-21T13:47:26.542Z baa565b5-a548-11e8-9585-8d99dc1af95e Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Please help how to submit 2 https requests with an interval/status of first request.  Thanks

Comment: Sleep is almost always the wrong solution to delay until some task is complete. Instead, some signal should be sent when its done. You should probably look into queues, both the external kind and the in memory kind.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda live up to a few hours, can process one request for up to five minutes. The only thing you are in control of, is its timeout. By default, it's set to 3 seconds. Here I set it to 30 seconds.

[image]

Nonetheless, what you're trying to accomplish is not 'lambdish' so I encourage you to look for a different solution. The main goal of lambdas is being asynchronous. Here you're wasting 2 minutes of its time.

You may want to consider adding the task to a queue (SQS, SNS) or to any SQL DB if it's a bigger project.

Even though, it will work with lambdas just fine. You just waste a lot of resources and lambdas are not designed to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Answer says 3 seconds. Image shows 30 seconds. Which is it?

Comment: Well, look at your config on AWS. I set 30 sec for my script. That's my config.

Answer (score -1):

I Cant test your code cause i dont have a token and i cant understand your API docs, but maybe you can input your second request in same scope of the first, so your second request will happens when the first finish and if the statuscode was 200. something like that, sory i cant test the code

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
domain = 'mydatabricks.cloud.databricks.com'
tokenStr = 'token:tokenstr'

response = requests.post('https://%s/api/2.0/clusters/start' % (domain),
           headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + base64.standard_b64encode(tokenStr)},
           json = {"cluster_id": "ddddd-sss23-2232323"})

if response.status_code == 200:
       response2 = requests.post('https://%s/api/2.0/jobs/run-now' % (domain),
                   headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + 
                   base64.standard_b64encode(tokenStr)},
                   json = {"job_id": 12345})

print(response2.statuscode)
```